# PostgreSQL copy issues

Tags: postgresql, copy, tableau-api

I am trying to copy my PostgreSQL query result set into an excel file since Tableau Public does not connect to PostgreSQL.

I am unsure how to get my result set into excel. I've been watching countless YouTube vids and read numerous stack overflow & postgresql threads to no avail. I am using postgresql 14 on pgadmin on a Mac. Appreciate any response!

The code below is what I tried and I get this error message:

```
copy (select * from emp) to '/Users/my_name/Desktop/sql_query.csv' with csv

ERROR:  could not open file "/Users/my_name/Desktop/sql_query.csv" for writing: Permission denied
HINT:  COPY TO instructs the PostgreSQL server process to write a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.
SQL state: 42501
```

I also tried \copy and got this error message:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 1: \copy (select * from emp) to '/Users/my_name/Desktop/sq...
        ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 1
```

Comment: This `syntax error at or near "\"` would indicate you are doing this in a client other then `psql`. Is that the case? To elaborate `COPY` is a SQL statement that can be run from any client `\copy` is a [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) meta-command  that only be run in the `psql` client.

Comment: to be honest im not completely sure if im in client. I also tried that in psql shell and nothing happened

Comment: If you where running in `psql` there should have been some sort of indication either success with `COPY  <some_number>` or an error message. If you are using `pgAdmin4` you can do the same thing here [Import/Export](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/6.17/import_export_data.html).

Comment: hm I guess I could save my result set into a table and then export that to excel. I am using pgadmin 4.

Comment: `select * from emp` is all columns and rows from the table `emp` you could use the `Export` dialog.

Comment: I used create table table_name as (query) and then exported to csv. I guess I'll have to do this work-around since I dont want to spend 2k on tableau desktop haha. thanks for the help.

Comment: Another option: 1) In Query Tool run  the query. 2) In Data Output click on select all arrow(top left) cell to select all the output 3) On Query Tool menu bar select Save results to file(far right icon w/down arrow). This will save to CSV.

Comment: Rather than spending your time on Youtube and Stackoverflow, try reading the documentation. It may be old-fashioned, but it has worked for others.